# MySQL - Получить записи за последние 7 дней, начиная с завтрашнего дня

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить записи за последние 7 дней, начиная с завтрашнего дня?

```
SELECT t.name, DATE_FORMAT(tt.date, '%Y-%m-%d') date FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "table t LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "table_two tt ON (t.course_id = tt.course) WHERE tt.location = '1' AND tt.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Вроде должно делаться через: `tt.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`
Но что-то выводит совсем не то что нужно.

Пример: "Если current_date='2019-02-22', то нужно вывести записи за период с 2019-02-23 по 2019-03-01".

Comment: "последние 7 дней с завтрашнего" это случайно не "последние 6 дней с сегодняшнего" ?

Comment: *последние 7 дней, начиная с завтрашнего * Нормальные люди считают в направлении увеличения. И эта фраза означает `от 'завтра' до 'через 8 дней'`.

Comment: И что такое "выходит не то, что нужно". Я вот вижу запятой на хватает в списке полей. У вас запрос вообще должен с ошибкой завершаться

Comment: @Mike нет, выводить данные за текущий день не нужно.

Comment: @Akina а можно без лишних комментариев?

Comment: @Mike "выходит не то, что нужно" - выходит не те дни которые нужны. На запятую не обращайте внимание.

Comment: @g4343 Если за сегодня выводить не нужно, то видимо надо добавить явное условие для этого, `tt.date < curdate()`. Обратите внимание, что now() дает дату с текущем временем и now() - 7 дней это сейчас вообще то 14 февраля 17:31

Comment: Сделал `tt.date > curdate()` по идеи должны выводится начиная с 22.02.2019. Оно так и есть, только вот после 28-го снова выводится 1 февраля и т.д.

Comment: *а можно без лишних комментариев?* Можно. Устраните неоднозначность в формулировке вопроса (например, сформулируйте дополнительный пример типа "если current_date='2019-02-22', то надо вывести записи за период с  2019-02-23 по 2019-03-02") - и они не потребуются. И, задавая вопрос по MySQL, убирайте из запроса PHP-шную обёртку.

Comment: @Akina и снова бесполезный комментарий от вас. Ладно, поправил вопрос.

Comment: `AND tt.date BETWEEN current_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND current_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY `. Если `tt.date` имеет тип datetime или timestamp, то `AND DATE(tt.date) BETWEEN ...`

Comment: @Akina То что нужно! Спасибо Вам большое!